# tortoisegit version 2.6.0.0 doesn't work authentication

Tags: github, tortoisegit

Today, I and my colleague get an error when I try to pull/push.
Yesterday everything worked.

1st step
[image]

I enter login and pass. ( log and pass are correct, checked on the git and entered it  10 times ).

2st step
[image]
3st step

[image]

I try to do it before the update and after. Also, I delete and reinstall tortoisegit. It didn't help.

**Someone knows what could happen?**

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the exact details, but git changed their authentication today. Something about removing and older, less secure authentication. I had a similar problem, and fixed it by reinstalling GitBash. The Git users in my office using Visual Studio had to install a Visual Studio update. So, I would start with Gitbash first, then look if Tortoise git has an update if bash does not fix your issue. Good luck!